# Error Code in R: "Log2 fold change is not numeric!"

Tags: r, ggplot2

first time trying to draw plots with RStudio. Just crammed in some new knowledge on the basics and not really knowing what to do here. I'm trying to draw a simple volcano plot with the package "EnhancedVolcan" for an excel spreadsheet that I've got. Here's the code that I used for the plot:

```
                lab = mRNA(DE_Results_HI_SCI_PLX_SCI_Veh),
                x = 'Log2 fold change',
                y = 'P-value',
                xlim = c(-5, 8))
```

For some inconcievable reason, the command returned an error saying that my x variable isn't numeric. But I checked all the variables with "str()" and this is the result that I got:

> $ Log2 fold change: num [1:602] -0.325 -0.232 -0.0873 -0.433 -0.334 -0.108 -0.621 -0.295 -0.287 -0.161

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but 'num' in the resultant list of variables means that it is in fact an numeric variable, doesn't it? Then why does the error message say that it isn't?

Comment: You don't show a lot of code... but assuming all that is inside `aes()`, your problem is that you're using strings. `ggplot` expects unquoted column names. Now, your column names are "non-standard", because they have spaces and dashes, so you actually need to use backticks, which is how R treats non-standard names in general. Also `xlim` **shouldn't** be inside `aes()` (or inside `ggplot()`, it can be "added" with a `+` to a ggplot), but you don't show enough code for me to be really sure what you're doing.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please show your complete plotting code, as well as a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I wasn't exactly using ggplot2 for that graph. I wasn't exactly how do this, so I just copied and edited the codes for a volcano plot from this website:

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I wasn't exactly using ggplot2 for that graph. I wasn't exactly how do this, so I just imported a excel spreadsheet into my rstudio program and then copied and edited the codes for a volcano plot from this website:
https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EnhancedVolcano/inst/doc/EnhancedVolcano.html

But now that I understand the process slightly better than 48 hours ago. I think my problem is: 1) should've used a csv file; 2) I wasn't using an actual data.frame?